# Process nested YAML file in scala

Tags: scala, yaml

I have a nested YAML file as below and I want to process it in scala  with snakeyaml.Yaml however I encounter an error:
Unable to find property 'myMap' on class MyConfig

Here is an example of the Yaml file that I have:

```
myMap:
-
 name: key1
 value: value1
-
 name: key2
 value: value2
```

I defined two classes for the YAML structure. I am using org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml to do yaml.load

```
class ConfigParamsKeyValue {
  @BeanProperty var name: String = null
  @BeanProperty var value: String = null
}

class MyConfig{
  @BeanProperty var myMap= new java.util.ArrayList[ConfigParamsKeyValue]();
}

def loadConfig(filename : String): MyConfig = {
   val yaml = new Yaml(new Constructor(classOf[MyConfig]))
   val stream = new FileInputStream(filename)
   try {
     val obj = yaml.load(stream)
     obj.asInstanceOf[MyConfig]
   } finally {
   stream.close()
  }
}
```

Comment: which library are you using for this?

Comment: I can not replicate your issue, with snakeyaml 1.8 it works

Comment: Thanks! I just found out the reason it did not work for me - I did not use camelcase in one of the fields as noted in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52619452/snakeyaml-unable-to-find-property-error