# Read yaml of same nested structure with different properties in scala

Tags: scala, yaml, snakeyaml

I am trying to make a generic function to read yaml files of same nested structure but different properties in scala using snakeYaml. Like one yaml could be

```
myMap:
-
 name: key1
 value: value1
-
 name: key2
 value: value2
```

Another yaml could be

```
myMap:
-
 name: key1
 value: value1
 data: data1
-
 name: key2
 value: value2
 data: data2
```

To read first yaml , I am able to read using below code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53920881/process-nested-yaml-file-in-scala) :

```
class configParamsKeyValue {
  @BeanProperty var name: String = null
  @BeanProperty var value: String = null
}

class myConfig{
  @BeanProperty var myMap= new java.util.ArrayList[configParamsKeyValue]();
}

def loadConfig(filename : String): myConfig = {
   val yaml = new Yaml(new Constructor(classOf[myConfig]))
   val stream = new FileInputStream(filename)
   try {
     val obj = yaml.load(stream)
     obj.asInstanceOf[myConfig]
   } finally {
   stream.close()
  }
}
```

I want to be able to pass this type configParamsKeyValue of ArrayList as parameter in class myConfig so that I can read second yaml file as well by defining another class like

```
class configParamsKeyValueData {
  @BeanProperty var name: String = null
  @BeanProperty var value: String = null
  @BeanProperty var data: String = null
}
```

Can some body please help

Comment: I don't know Scala, but couldn't you just make `myConfig` generic taking the type inside the `ArrayList` as generic parameter?

Comment: that's what I am trying to achieve but not sure how can I do it in scala!